# How to catch TinyTds::Error on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, tiny-tds

I want to make things failsafe.

If the database server is down, or something goes wrong, TinyTds throws TinyTds::Error. But I can't catch that error. All I want to do is to write log for that and show an error page for user.

I've searched long time but I can't find how.

Comment: What do you mean by you "can't"? Are you not allowed to do that for some system reason? Or, are you failing to do so after trying?

Comment: `rescue TinyTds::Error => error` ?

Comment: I think it is not a controller level. It is Rack middleware level issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. This is not controller-level issue, and thus, it is obvious that I can't catch an error which is not a controller level.

I've solved with `exception_handler` gem. With that gem, I can bypass the stock  middleware and customize the behavior when I got `TinyTds::Error`